# how to replace values in a non unique index in Series in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

In the picture, I wanted to change the value "Philosophy" of the index "Kelly", but I can't change the value. Using set_value method.

Comment: Please post your code as code, not an image. And post a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Use the ".loc" accessor with a list of booleans.
First construct your list of booleans.
You want the index == 'Kelly' and the value == 'Philosophy'.

```
bool_list = (all_students_classes.index == 'Kelly') & (all_students_classes == 'Philosophy')
```

Then pass this list of booleans to the ".loc" accessor and assign a new value

```
all_student_classes[bool_list] = 'Not Philosophy'
```